# Как обьединить 2 столбца в один?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть таблица sys_modul (Postgre), состоящая из двух заполненных столбцов(строки) mainsyst, modul и одного не заполненного res.
Как мне заполнить столбец res данными из mainsyst и modul? Т.е. необходимо их построчно слить(с пробелом), и чтобы данные из mainsyst были в скобках!

Получим: см.картинку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то типа `UPDATE sys_modul SET res = '(' || mainsyst || ') ' || modul`... только делать это надо в запросе, а поле в таблице для этого не нужно.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, работает